# I feel no pain, yet silently shriek

Tags: riddle, wordplay

I feel no pain
Yet silently shriek
An airy concoction
Your desire I pique
A sinful temptation
You seldom refuse
As I squeal, howl and bellow
I delight and amuse

**Who am I?**

Comment: Is this riddle from Hyōka?

Comment: @FurkanOmay, I don't think so. In Hyōka, the wordplay is not discovered through a riddle. Oreki eventually understands the situation of the creator of the magazine and can trace back his inspiration for that particular name.

Comment: @FurkanOmay no, I came up with it myself.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**Answer:**

I feel no pain
Yet silently shriek

> is a play on "ice cream" and "I scream"

An airy concoction
Your desire I pique

> That's me and ice cream, all right.

A sinful temptation
You seldom refuse

> Sugar and heart-clogging fat. BRING IT!!!

As I squeal, howl and bellow
I delight and amuse.

> I'd explain this as well but I'm going to go get some ice cream now.

Comment: Seriously? THIS is the accepted answer?

Comment: @mathgenius And the problem with that is...? It's accepted because it's what the OP had in mind when creating the puzzle, not because you personally like it or not.

Comment: @underscore_d, The problem is that it makes no sense, from *any* logical standpoint. Stringing together a bunch of words and posing as an "explanation" does not prove a theory - the fart answer below makes more sense. Although you are right about something - if the OP just wanted some random guy to write a random thing on his random string of words, then it is perfect, but then again this is pretty much what "Puzzling" is all about, isn't it, no matter if you personally like it or not.

Comment: @mathgenius Well, although it's a little vaguely written, I thought the answer indicates its reasoning fairly well (alluding to the pun, the air content of the medium, its addictive qualities...), but I can sorta see your point that it's not methodically explained, which would be more ideal. Fair point.

Comment: Since when is "I'd explain this as well but I'm going to go get some ice cream now." an answer? Let alone an acceptable one.

Comment: Okay let me spell it out: "squeal", "howl", and "bellow" are synonyms for "scream" -- thus, "I scream". "I delight and amuse" -- ice cream does this; of course me screaming may also delight and amuse some o_O

Comment: @Daedric Because the part of the riddle he's referring to there is a callback to a part that has already been explained.

Comment: @question_asker tell it to the judge XD

Comment: @Daedric what  .

Comment: @question_asker Judge is Big Black Box

Comment: @manshu I know! And he selected this as the answer! And the answer makes perfect sense and is well-explained! I don't know why people are losing their marbles over this one.

Comment: @question_asker totally agree with you...but the answer alone doesn't matter..the thing that matter more is how you represent it...this (full) answer could have been much better if the answerer had explained it well...jokes looks better in a comment but not in an answer...

Comment: @mathgenius to confirm what others have said, this riddle was written precisely with this solution in mind. The fact that someone else was able to see my intent and find my intended solution using nothing but the information provided in the riddle (assuming that I and Hugh Meyers are two different people and didn't communicate with each other, which you'll have to take my word is the case) disproves your assertion that this answer "makes no sense". He also explained pretty much everything that wasn't self-explanatory, except one small thing: ...

Comment: ... "amuse and delight" in the last line refers both to the delight in eating ice cream, and to the amusing effect that people find in the similarity of the pronunciation of the two phrases "ice cream" and "I scream". But in any case the solution is very well written and the humorous effect in the "explanation" of the last clue makes it better (in my opinion), not worse.

Comment: @question_asker Says the person who needs no less than two exclamation points to signal their bewilderment "!".

Answer (score 70):

You're a:

> Fart.

I feel no pain

> No pain involved.

Yet silently shriek

> But are demanding to come out.

An airy concoction

> Made of air.

Your desire I pique

> One wants to let it rip.

A sinful temptation

> But it's gonna stink and might be quite loud.

You seldom refuse

> Most people let it rip sooner or later.

As I squeal, howl and bellow

> Making all sorts of noise.

I delight and amuse

> But farts are very funny, if perhaps, in a puerile way.

Comment: LOL, LMAO...it is the most funniest answer i have ever read...:D

Comment: Indeed this is a terrific answer (though not the one I had in mind), and is a nice fit for pretty much all the clues... except for the "wordplay" tag. The correct answer makes use of that in a crucial way.

Comment: This literally made me laugh out loud. I like this much better than the accepted answer!

Comment: 'Sinful' doesn't fit though. No downvote - answer is otherwise pretty funny.

Comment: Hahaha, good one :-D

Comment: If one had the power to change the accepted answer I'd pick this one.  This is great.

Comment: I joined purely so I could up vote this answer :D

Comment: @Phill: same here! This answer is pure genius!

Comment: @manshu Thank you, you're far too kind. I wasn't going to post, fearing I might offend.  Apologies to anyone I did, only meant to give people a giggle :) )

Comment: This kind of answer can never offend anybody...Just in case if someone had said that he is offended then I would have directly pointed out that he doesn't have monopoly over the farts...They belong to all...and will always be. :D

Answer (score 4):

I feel no pain
Yet silently shriek.

> So it makes noise without pain

An airy concoction.

> Contains air

Your desire I pique.

> Works on demand whenever you want

A sinful temptation,
You seldom refuse.

> Can be used to play pranks on someone

As I squeal, howl and bellow, 
I delight and amuse.

> In the end always amuses

Is it

> a whoopee cushion.
> That's what first crossed my mind, and then I saw fart, now I am more sure of >!my answer